# How to apply paper background in python using pillow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to put paper background with this picture to create an old image, also some colors (colors are not important). I used to do it in GIMP by putting paper as layer above (layermask) and and putting down transparency. Don't have any ideas how to do it in python, do you?

[image]
Photo by [Julia Maior](https://unsplash.com/@juliamaior?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText) on [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/s/photos/paper?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText)

[image]
Photo by [amir rabiee](https://unsplash.com/@amir__rbe?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText) on [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/s/photos/old-image?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) Library for Python.
It is a modern forked version of PIL used for image processing.

Only install Pillow and not PIL. They are two seperate packages.

> python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

Here is the offical Github Repo:
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow

I've used your images to make what I believe you wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from PIL import Image

Im = Image.open("car.jpg")

Im2 = Image.open("crumble_paper.jpg").convert(Im.mode)
Im2 = Im2.resize(Im.size)

img = Image.blend(Im,Im2,0.3)
img.save('crumble_paper_car.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfect, thank you very much!